# iPad, iPhone Safari Browser - Time issue, 5 hours difference

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, datetime

```
const pickupDate = format(this.pickupAddressComponent.pickupDate, 'YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss');
```

I had an issue with time in iPad and iPhone safari browser.

I selected the 11:00 AM pickup time (this is how it's storing "2019-07-30T11:00:00"), when I retrieve it from the local store the time is changed and showing as 06:00 AM (5 hours difference). and it is only happening in iPad, iPhone safari browser, any idea what's the issue/root cause is ??

Comment: Did you try storing it with timezone (GMT+0200)? 
For example like new Date(): Tue Jul 30 2019 17:55:12 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

Comment: I'm not doing any kind of conversions, can you give me some examples ?? @N.Tasikj

Comment: Yes you are doing some format and problem is probably in timezones, because you don't have timezone in "2019-07-30T11:00:00" safari is converting it in some other timezone

Comment: What is the best solution to handle in safari and shouldn't break in other browser ?? @N.Tasikj

Comment: `"2019-07-30T11:00:00"` is parsed as local time.  `"2019-07-30T11:00:00Z"` is parsed as UTC time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause,

I'm using ngRx store module and added the `restoreDates` flag and set it to false in index.ts and it's working as expected.

> `restoreDates` *(boolean? = true)*: Restore serialized date objects.
>   If you work directly with ISO date strings, set this option to `false`.

for reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage